# Slicing a string with standard indexing

Tags: python, string, reverse

Why isn't this functioning properly? I'm aware of the advanced slice ([::-1]) option but I would like to figure out how to reverse the str this way as well.

```
word = input("Please enter a word to reverse: ")

cut = len(word)
print(word[cut:-cut])
```

Comment: `-cut` means `cut` steps from the end of the string.

Comment: @user2387370 Post that comment as the answer please ;)

Comment: Why doesnt the negative symbol function then in this circumstance?

Comment: I do not understand you distinction between 'standard' and 'advanced' slicing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation  which explains this well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word[cut:-cut]
```

May go from `cut` to `-cut`, which you could also write

```
word[cut:0]
```

but the *step* is still 1, which is *still positive*. So it will slice *forward* from the end, and stop because it's reached the end!

This implies that the step is needed either way, `word[cut:-cut:-1]`. When indexing backwards, both indexes need to reduced by one, so you have `word[cut-1:-cut-1:-1]`, or `word[cut-1:-6:-1]`, or even just `word[::-1]`. Note that `-1` as the end parameter will be mangled back to the end of the string!

Comment: You'd have to use `word[cut-1:-1:-1]`, actually.

Comment: @Martijn, nope, that doesn't work either.  In slices, Python adds the length of the sequence to any negative index first.  So your middle `-1` magically changes into `len(word) - 1`, and the slice is actually empty!  Try it ;-)  This just doesn't work the same way as the arguments to `range` or `xrange`.  `word[cut-1::-1]` works (leave out the middle argument).

Comment: @TimPeters: Argh, you are right, forgot about that corner case. No way to specify an end value of `-1` because negative values are overloaded..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, don't feel bad - I forget it several times each year - LOL ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify a negative step, slices always go forwards. Specifying a start position after the end of the slice will only produce an empty slice. You need the negative step.